# Laravel Search Caching

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel (and coding in general), and I have a little Pizza Ordering system that stores the orders placed by clients to a local Pizzaria.

Inside the "New Order" form, when you start typing down the name of a pizza (four cheeses, chicken, yada yada), the program returns a query search that is run every 2 keydowns with products with a similar name.

Here's the search query, a pretty simple and basic one:

```
    $pesquisa = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $produtos = Produto::select('nome', 'valor')->where('nome', 'LIKE', '%'.$pesquisa.'%')->get();
    return response()->json($produtos);
```

Here's the "problem" I'm having: The current database has about 50 items, and it takes about ~500ms to get a return. This in my local machine, the problem gets a little bigger when it's actually hosted in a server, where it can spike from ~500ms to ~2s, depending on user connection.

In my study, I've heard about caching, and that it can shorten or remove the need for queries (which was already implemented in the "show all orders placed" list, and REALLY minimized the speed of loading), but I don't know if caching can be done with user-inputted search?

First question: How would one go about saving those pizza names to a cache, while still sorting through them based on user input?

Second question: Is caching like this the "best" way to speed up user-inputted search? Is there something else I should be doing first? (I've heard that the 'LIKE' query search is the slowest there is... should I research and try another type?)

All explanations, tips and tricks are greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: 500ms for searching a 50 item database is too much. Maybe you should try to find what takes so long first.

Comment: What database engine are you using? Eg. MySQL, Postgres, etc

Comment: As apokryfos mentioned, it's unlikely the 500ms on local is a database issue, assuming you're using a mainstream database engine. A database query like this on local (in my experience) should take less than 10ms. If you move this from database to cache, there's a good chance it won't help. 

To answer your questions, you can use Cache::get() based on user input. But Cache is usually key/value pairs and you should already know the key when searching, so it's not ideal for a LIKE query, since the user input won't match the Produto name exactly.

Comment: Some more tips.. some may seem obvious sorry. Using the browser dev tools Network tab, confirm that the 500ms is all happening on the server, and it's not JavaScript detecting when you have stopped typing for 500ms before performing the request (this is common practice with real-time search). Run the query directly on the local database, not from the PHP server... if it is a database issue, it may not be a *query* issue. Try the request without performing a database query, eg. change your whole function to `return response()->json([]);` - see if it still takes ~500ms.

Answer (score 2):

For Caching you can use this

```
  $pesquisa = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

  return Cache::remember($pesquisa, $seconds, function ()use($pesquisa) {
           $produtos = Produto::select('nome', 'valor')->where('nome', 'LIKE', '%'.$pesquisa.'%')->get();
           return response()->json($produtos);
   });
```

rememberForever can also be used instead of remember